# Inserting Custom Action between Dialogs (InstallUISequence) in WiX

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, custom-action

I have two custom dialog boxes (plus the required ones `ExitDlg`, `FatalErrorDlg`, etc.), the first one sets a property using an Edit control and the second one shows this property using a Text control. Here is the meaningful code:

```xml
<Dialog Id="DialogA" ...>
  <Control Id="ControlEdit" Type="Edit" Property="MY_PROPERTY" .../>
  <Control Id="ControlNext" Type="PushButton" ...>
    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" /></Control>
</Dialog>
```

And then the second dialog:

```xml
<Dialog Id="DialogB" ...>
  <Control Id="ControlText" Type="Text" Text="[MY_PROPERTY]" .../>
  <Control Id="ControlBack" Type="PushButton" ...>
    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" /></Control>
  <Control Id="ControlNext" Type="PushButton" ...>
    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" /></Control>
</Dialog>
```

And the action sequence:

```xml
<InstallUISequence>
   <Show Dialog="DialogA" Before="MyCustomAction" />
   <Custom Action="MyCustomAction" Before="DialogB" />
   <Show Dialog="DialogB" Before="ExecuteAction" />
</InstallUISequence>
```

The custom action changes the value of `MY_PROPERTY`. My problem is how to make the Back button in `DialogB`get back to `DialogA`. Using `NewDialog` is simple, but then I can't get the custom action to be executed between the dialogs, or can I?

---

**edit - 2013-05-02**

After the answer from @caveman_dick, I tried to change the `DialogA` almost like he said, but instead of using `EndDialog`, I changed to `Action="NewDialog" Value="DialogB"`. But now the Custom Action isn't being called. If I remove the Publish event to go to next dialog, then the CA is called. If I leave as @caveman_dick said, I can't get back to `DialogA` from `DialogB`.

---

**edit - 2013-05-02**

After searching in book *WiX 3.6: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML*, I found the following: "if you have more than one Publish event, they must have conditional statements as their inner text. Otherwise, all of the events simply won't be published."

So the answer from @caveman_dick is correct, except that you need to change to the following:

```xml
<Publish ...>1</Publish>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than scheduling the custom action in the `InstallUISequence` you can publish it on the button click:

```
<Dialog Id="DialogA" ...>
   <Control Id="ControlEdit" Type="Edit" Property="MY_PROPERTY" .../>
   <Control Id="ControlNext" Type="PushButton" ...>
       <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="MyCustomAction">1</Publish>
       <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
   </Control>
</Dialog>
```

EDIT: The `Publish` element's condition needs to explicitly evaluate to true to run, so add `"1"` as the text of the `Publish` elements.

Comment: I tried your approach but the action isn't being called. Instead of using `EndDialog`, I'm using `NewDialog` to be able to get back. If I remove the event `NewDialog`, the action is called.

Comment: As edited in question, you need to add the condition to get multiple events working, but your answer is partially correct and solves the problem.

Comment: I was just about to edit the answer with that. I naughtily copy-pasted your code. Thanks for the recognition though! :)