# How to execute spesific method from MSI dialog

Tags: c#, installation, orca

How to execute spesific method from MSI dialog?
I already try create custom dialog using ORCA and insert data in ControlEvent section like this :

```
Dialog       | Control    | Event    | Argument        | Condition | Order
CustomTextD  | NextButton | DoAction | CheckConnection | 0         | 0
```

These result are failed. I declare CheckConnection() method in Installer Class.
What i try to accomplish here is checking connection to database on "button next" clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using Orca is not the easiest way to create an MSI package. If you want a free tool try [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/).
The [following SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336684/inserting-custom-action-between-dialogs-installuisequence-in-wix) explains how you to call a custom action from a push button.

Basically, you need to define your custom action, without sequence. Then add a control event for the desired button, with a DoAction call that will execute your custom action.

Comment: thanks bogdan for your direction..may i know where exactly i have to declare custom action method? is it in installer class?