# C# fetch values during setup project

Tags: c#, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I want to fetch values of custom textbox values Email_ID and Serial_key created during setup in c#. I went through some stack overflow answers and got to know need to override Installer class

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
         base.Install(stateSaver);

}
```

I want to know where to write this class and how to fetch values in this installer class.[During setup I want to fetch this textbox values and send to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKFfS.jpg)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131830/c-sharp-visual-studio-project-installer-save-data-from-textbox-into-textfile/47164481#47164481  and most of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131830/c-sharp-visual-studio-project-installer-save-data-from-textbox-into-textfile/47164481#47164481

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a custom install program and override `Install` method inside that.

> In the Solution Explorer, right click on the project name and choose
>   'Add' > 'New Item' and then choose 'Installer Class' from the New Item
>   dialog.

Refer this as a [startup](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/0df20605-b457-42d6-b63c-341a3824474a.htm)

The user input values will be available in the `Context.Parameters` object. Look at [this](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/InstallerClassSample.htm)

Comment: Thanks..Now, I have created Installer Class but how to fetch those values in that class?.